# Why does ModelBuilder addGeometry function throw error

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I want to add a custom geometry to my model in the forge viewer. To do so, I use the model builder extension, but the modelBuilder.addGeometry function throws the following error:

thirdparty/three.js/three.js:33
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

```js
const sceneBuilder: any = await this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
const modelBuilder: any = await sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
    modelNameOverride: 'My Custom Model',
    conserveMemory: false
});

const geometry: THREE.Geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    
let vertexIndex = 0;
// room is a custom object coming from our database containing 2D geometrical information
    for (let i = 1; i < room.Outline.Vertices.length; i++) {
      const bimV1 = room.Outline.Vertices[i - 1];
      const bimV2 = room.Outline.Vertices[i];
      if (i === 1) {
        const v1 = new THREE.Vector3(bimV1.X, bimV1.Y, room.Zbase);
        const v2 = new THREE.Vector3(bimV1.X, bimV1.Y, room.Zbase + 5);
        geometry.vertices.push(v1);
        geometry.vertices.push(v2);
      }
      
      const v3 = new THREE.Vector3(bimV2.X, bimV2.Y, room.Zbase);      
      const v4 = new THREE.Vector3(bimV2.X, bimV2.Y, room.Zbase + 5);
      
      geometry.vertices.push(v3);      
      geometry.vertices.push(v4);

      const face1 = new THREE.Face3(vertexIndex, vertexIndex + 1, vertexIndex + 2);
      const face2 = new THREE.Face3(vertexIndex + 1, vertexIndex + 2, vertexIndex + 3);

      geometry.faces.push(face1);
      geometry.faces.push(face2);

      vertexIndex += 2;
    }

geometry.computeFaceNormals();

const bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(geometry);
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(0, 0, 1), opacity: 0.5 });
const transform = new THREE.Matrix4().identity();
modelBuilder.addMaterial('MyCustomMaterial', material);
const geometryId = modelBuilder.addGeometry(geometry);
const cylinderFragId = modelBuilder.addFragment(geometryId, 'MyCustomMaterial', transform);
```

What causes this error? It works, when I am using a three cylinder like this:

```js
const sceneBuilder: any = await this.viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.SceneBuilder');
const modelBuilder: any = await sceneBuilder.addNewModel({
    modelNameOverride: 'My Custom Model',
    conserveMemory: false
});
const cylinderGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(5, 5, 10));
const cylinderMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(0, 0, 1) });
const cylinderTransform = new THREE.Matrix4().compose(
    new THREE.Vector3(+10, +10, 0),
    new THREE.Quaternion(0, 0, 0, 1),
    new THREE.Vector3(1, 1, 1)
);
modelBuilder.addMaterial('MyCustomMaterial', cylinderMaterial);
const cylinderGeomId = modelBuilder.addGeometry(cylinderGeometry);
const cylinderFragId = modelBuilder.addFragment(cylinderGeomId, 'MyCustomMaterial', cylinderTransform);
```

I already tried to use BufferGeometry as well, but that didn't help...

Edit:
I also tried to use the 'ConvexGeomtry' class:

```
let vertices :THREE.Vector3[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < room.Outline.Vertices.length; i++) {
  const bimV1 = room.Outline.Vertices[i];
  vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(bimV1.X, bimV1.Y, bimV1.Zbase));
  vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(bimV1.X, bimV1.Y, bimV1.Zbase + 5));
}

const geometry = new ConvexGeometry(vertices);

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: new THREE.Color(0, 0, 1), opacity: 0.5 });
const transform = new THREE.Matrix4().identity();
modelBuilder.addMaterial('MyCustomMaterial', material);
const geometryId = modelBuilder.addGeometry(geometry);
modelBuilder.addFragment(geometryId, 'MyCustomMaterial', transform);
```

It throws the same error when calling 'modelBuilder.addGeometry(geometry)'

Comment: The code you mention - both for your custom geometry and for the cylinder - looks ok to me, which makes me think that the problem could be in the one part you did not include here and that's the generation of your custom geometry. Can you add that piece to your question?

Comment: Hi Petr
Thank you for your answer. I added the code, where vertices and faces are added. I don't understand which object, possessing a position attribute, could possibly be undefined...

Comment: To make sure, that the geometry gets set up correctly, I used the 'ConvexGeometry' class only passing my points in a array of vertices. Nevertheless, I get the same error when calling 'modelBuilder.addGeometry(geometry)'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's an error in your code snippet. While you are converting your `THREE.Geometry` object into `THREE.BufferGeometry` object (required by Forge Viewer), you are passing the wrong variable into the `modelBuilder.addGeometry` method.

Try replacing

```js
const geometryId = modelBuilder.addGeometry(geometry);
```

with

```js
const geometryId = modelBuilder.addGeometry(bufferGeometry);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing me in the right direction. I tried the bufferGeometry before, but it was not working. When I removed 'import * as THREE from 'three';' from my code and instead used 'declare var THREE: any;' to reference THREE, my code did run. Of course, your answer is correct as well and it only works with the bufferGeometry. Thank you again for your quick help!